# How to retrieve thumbnails and display them as QListwidget items?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

**I am trying to read the thumbnails directly from http://i.ytimg.com/ without using google gdata services. Can anyone help me?**

```
`enter code here`

#!/usr/bin/env python
#_*_ encoding: UTF-8 _*_

from PyQt4.QtGui import QImageReader

from PyQt4.QtNetwork import (QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply, QNetworkAccessManager)

from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl


def getThumbnails(self,numTitles):

     thumbs = []
     thumbs[:]= []

     nam = QNetworkAccessManager()

     for i in xrange(numTitles):
         url = QUrl("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + self.tubeLinks[i] + "/default.jpg")
         request = QNetworkRequest(url)
         reply = nam.get(request)
         image_reader = QImageReader(reply)
         thumbs.append(image_reader.read())

     return thumbs
```

**My delimmas are:**

1.- how to test whether or not the thumb was successfully read?

2.- how to add them add them to QListWidget item using pixmap?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably solve it using 2 objects:

1.- A subclass of QListWidgetItem that holds the image you want, the logic of how to load the image as a QPixmap, etc. This should be the item you should insert to the list.

2.- A QItemDelegate that defines how items in the QListWidget are drawn. Here you can handle the cases for when the items (QListWidgetItem objects) have an empty image and display a default icon.

Here's extra documentation on Item delegates. Good luck

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes